# Missing step in differentiability implies continuity.

Tags: limits

I want to prove the following statement:

Let $I$ be some interval in $\mathbb{R}$, that is $I \subset \mathbb{R}$

Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable in $a$. Then $f$ is continuous in $a$.

Proof:

Notice that $f(x)-f(a)=(x-a) \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

We can restrict the function to $I \setminus \{a\}$ and call it $f_0$.

Then notice that:
$\lim_{x\to a}f_0(x) -f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)·  \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_0(x)-f(a)}{x-a}= 0 · f'(a)=0$, by using the above.

So we conclude that $\lim_{x\to a}f_0(x) =f(a)$.

Now how do I conclude from this that

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) =f(a)$?

Comment: Because $f_0(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain $I-\{a\}$. Think about the  definition of "$\lim\limits_{x\to a}$."

Comment: You mean to say that if it is true that whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f_0(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$, it is also true that whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(a)|< \epsilon$?, because $f(x)=f_0(x)$ in close proximity of $a$, as long as we don't let $x$ be equal to $a$.

Comment: No, specifically $0<|x-a|<\delta$. So $x=a$ is not allowed.

Comment: But can you still make the argument then? or does it break down?

Comment: Whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$, $|f_0(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$, then whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $ is what we want to claim.

Comment: The point is that when $x=a$, $|f(x)-f(a)| = |f(a)-f(a)| = 0 < \epsilon$ is automatic.

Comment: Oh wow, you're completely right.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Whenever $x=a$, $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(a)-f(a)|<0<\epsilon$.

2)For all other values of $x$ in the domain, we notice that $f_0(x)$ converges to $f(a)$ as $ x \rightarrow a $.

With these two facts combined we can say that whenever $x \rightarrow a$, we notice that $f(x)  \rightarrow f(a)$. Consequently, $f(x)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of differentiability for each component we have that

$$f_i(a+h)=f_i(a)+f'_i(a)\cdot h + o(h)$$

then taking the limit both sides

$$\lim_{h\to 0} f_i(a+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}f_i(a)+f_i(a)\cdot h + o(h)=f_i(a)$$

that is

$$\lim_{x\to a} f_i(x)=f_i(a)$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$$

Comment: You're not reading carefully. $f$ is a function of a single real variable.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ops...ok it is $f:I\subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$